# bootstrap 4 dropdown scrollable: for long drop down lists

Tags: dropdown, bootstrap-4

does anyone know how to modify BS 4 dropdown for very long lists that flow off of the bottom of the screen?  I want a vertical scroll bar to appear.

Thanks

Comment: I've just checked one of my dropdown lists. It is there by default. Where is your code?

Comment: Late reply. It looks like the same question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47645634/bootstrap-4-making-dropdown-scrollable